# Activity Data Passing Android Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, android-activity, mobile, xamarin

I currently have the following logic to pass data between Activities.

```
Intent resumeMainActivity = new Intent (this, typeof(RecordNowController));
resumeMainActivity.PutExtra ("EditedData", editContent);
StartActivity(resumeMainActivity);
```

The data passes through fine but it recreates the activity.

```
 Intent resumeMainActivity = new Intent (this, typeof(RecordNowController));
 resumeMainActivity.PutExtra ("EditedData", editContent);
 -->resumeMainActivity.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ReorderToFront);
 resumeMainActivity.PutExtra ("EditedData", editContent);
 StartActivity(resumeMainActivity);
```

Adding that line resumes my current activity instead of creating a fresh one. However for some reason the data won't pass through.

Does anybody know why this is?

Thank you.

Comment: That second put extra on the right is a typo error , its not there in the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive only just seen your reply but thank you.

I ended up using the StartActivityForResult() to start the activity and it works fine.

Reference: http://windingroadway.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/one-thing-that-is-really-important-to.html

Answer (score 0):

That is the default behavior, if you don't want a new one created, then use

`resumeMainActivity.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop);`

From the docs:

Whether or not the activity can move from the task that started it to the task it has an affinity for when that task is next brought to the front — "true" if it can move, and "false" if it must remain with the task where it started.
If this attribute is not set, the value set by the corresponding allowTaskReparenting attribute of the `<application>` element applies to the activity. The default value is "false".

Normally when an activity is started, it's associated with the task of the activity that started it and it stays there for its entire lifetime. You can use this attribute to force it to be re-parented to the task it has an affinity for when its current task is no longer displayed. Typically, it's used to cause the activities of an application to move to the main task associated with that application.

For example, if an e-mail message contains a link to a web page, clicking the link brings up an activity that can display the page. That activity is defined by the browser application, but is launched as part of the e-mail task. If it's reparented to the browser task, it will be shown when the browser next comes to the front, and will be absent when the e-mail task again comes forward.

The affinity of an activity is defined by the taskAffinity attribute. The affinity of a task is determined by reading the affinity of its root activity. Therefore, by definition, a root activity is always in a task with the same affinity. Since activities with "singleTask" or "singleInstance" launch modes can only be at the root of a task, re-parenting is limited to the "standard" and "singleTop" modes. (See also the launchMode attribute.)

The SingleTop will pass the data just fine.